# How to view internet-passwords from Keychain using Java (mac)

Tags: java, terminal, passwords, keychain, inputstreamreader

I would like to create a simple java app (for mac) that takes in a website and outputs my password associated with the website in Keychain.

My problem is that my app can't read the password from the output. If I manually write:

```
security find-internet-password -gs www.google.com
```

into the Terminal I get a few lines of info and then -> password: "mypassword". But in my application I only see the lines of info but the last line which should be the password is not there or null.

My code:

```
public static void command(){
    try{

        String command = "security find-internet-password -gs www.google.com";
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream()));
        String s;

        while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println(r.readLine());
        r.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors but simply the code above is not showing the password. I'm using Eclipse if that matters. Thanks

The application prints:

```
keychain: "/Users/*username*/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
class: "inet"
attributes:
    0x00000007 <blob>="www.google.com"
    0x00000008 <blob>=<NULL>
    "acct"<blob>="*username*"
    "atyp"<blob>="http"
    "cdat"<timedate>=0x323031*numbers*3333325A00  "2011*numbers*132Z\000"
    "crtr"<uint32>="rimZ"
    "cusi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "desc"<blob>=<NULL>
    "icmt"<blob>=<NULL>
    "invi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "mdat"<timedate>=0x3230331*numbers*33834375A00  "20115*numbers*3847Z\000"
    "nega"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "path"<blob>="/"
    "port"<uint32>=0x00000000 
    "prot"<blob>=<NULL>
    "ptcl"<uint32>="htps"
    "scrp"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "sdmn"<blob>="www.google.com"
    "srvr"<blob>="www.google.com"
    "type"<uint32>=<NULL>
```

but the last line is missing and should be

```
password: "mypassword"
```

**Edited**

Is it the InputStreamReader that does not read the password? Is there another way to get the password?

Comment: can you show us what is printed in general? and what should be printed instead. does the program complete?

Comment: @LoganMurphy I added what it prints

Comment: have tried running java from the command line? might have to run as admin

Comment: @LoganMurphy not sure what you mean but I am admin and when I run the app (or type the code in terminal) I get a message that asks if security is allowed to access confidential info stored in "www.google.com" in your keychain, which I answer allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you do not get the password in the output is that it is not printed to the stdout but to the stderr instead.

If you replace `child.getInputStream()` with `child.getErrorStream()` in your code will get you righ that `Password:secret!` line.

You could use e.g. the following modified version of your code:

```
public static boolean command(String host) {
    try {

        String command = "security find-internet-password -gs " + host;
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        try (BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                child.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(child.getErrorStream()))) {
            String user = null;
            String password = null;
            String s;

            while ((s = out.readLine()) != null) {
                if (s.matches(" *\"acct\".*")) {
                    user = s.replaceAll("^.*=\"", "").replace("\"", "");
                }
            }
            s = err.readLine();
            password = s.replaceAll("^.*: *\"", "").replace("\"", "");
            System.out.println("user: " + user);
            System.out.println("pwd: " + password);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```